# Check the equility of two string in array and change content of one of them

Tags: c

i'm tring a simple think but i won't be succeed.I want to check content of one array which inside an array already, whether it is equal "&" or not and I want to change content of array to NULL.

```
main(){
    char *line=lsh_read_line();
    char **args=lsh_split_line(line);
    char test[2];

    strcpy(test,"&");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(strcmp(args[i],test)){
            strcpy(args[i],NULL);
            printf("same");
        }
```

New Versiyon:

```
    main(){
    char *line=lsh_read_line();
    char **args=lsh_split_line(line);
    int n=sizeof(args);
    int size=n/sizeof(char*);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(strcmp(args[i],"&")==0){
            args[i]=NULL;
            printf("same");
        }
    }
    }
```

2.It is the new versiyon of code which runs more properly but size of array is not correct.
Below I explain my problem well.

```
    int main(){
    char **example=malloc(100*sizeof(char*))
    example[0]="ali";
    example[1]="mehmet";
    example[3]="ayse";
    int i=sizeof(example);
    int size=i/sizeof(char*);
    printf("%d",size);
```

}

Output is 1.Why?How can i get correct result?

Comment: `strcmp(args[i],test)` -> `strcmp(args[i],test) == 0`

Comment: `strcmp()` returns _zero_ if its arguments point to strings that are equal, but you're checking for a nonzero return to print "same". Also, `strcpy(args[i], NULL)` is undefined behavior: the second argument must be a pointer to a valid string. To empty the string, pass `""`, or simply write `args[i][0] = '\0';`.

Comment: `strcpy(args[i],NULL);` -> `args[i] = NULL;`

Comment: You should also be receiving a compiler warning about that same line regarding `"null argument where non-null required"`.

Comment: Thank you guys, you solved very well.However, i got still a problem which is segmentation fault.Even, i run properly the program,it still there.What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to interpret "I want to change content of array to NULL".

If you just want to change the pointer to `NULL`, just assign  it the value `NULL` without using `strcpy`.

If you just want to invalidate the null-terminated string contained in the array, set the first element of the array to `'\0'`: `args[i][0] = '\0';`

If you want to populate the entire array with null values, use `memset(args[i], 0, <size of args[i] array>)`